# Formatting a multidimensional array of image sprites

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, sprite

I am making a function that loads sprites for a game and not quite sure I know how to do it. I am still feeling my way around javascript and OOP so it's kind of lost on me. I need to select the sprites by the spritesheet they're in, and by an index that corresponds to the sprites location in the spritesheet. I want to refer to the spritesheet with a letter and the XY position by a number. Something like `Tile("A", 132);` The spritesheets will be 512x512 pixels containing sprites each 32x32 pixels big making 256 sprites total per sheet with multiple sheets. Here is what I have so far:

```
function Tileset(Spritesheet, Index){
    this.Spritesheet=Spritesheet;
    this.Index=Index;
    this.SpritesheetList=["TilesetA.png","TilesetB.png","TilesetC.png"];
    this.Tile=Image;
    this.LoadTiles = function(){
        for (sheet in SpritesheetList){
            var dummyImage= new Image;
            dummyImage.src=this.SpritesheetList[sheet];
            SpritesheetList[sheet]=[];
            for (var Y=0; Y<16; Y++){
                for (var X=0; X<16; X++){
                    this.SpritesheetList[sheet][Y*16 + X]=dummyImage.getSubimage(X*32, Y*32, 32, 32);
                };
            };
        };
        return this.SpritesheetList[Spritesheet][Index];
    };
    return this.SpritesheetList[Spritesheet][Index];
};
```

Comment: You're misusing `for..in`. `SpritesheetList` is an array, you should use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Also you forgot to declare `sheet`, and did you mean `this.SpritesheetList`?

Comment: Actually for that bit I was thinking the `for..in` would parse through all elements of the array till it reached the end. Am I doing it wrong naming the elements of the array though?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code. I don't know if you are using any library, but if the tiles have a size of 32x32 pixels, the last two arguments of getSubimage should be 32.

You should also try to only load the tiles once and not every time you access a tile.

I refactored your code a bit to make it more OOP and reusable.

```
function Tileset(spritesheetImages) {
    this.spritesheetImages = spritesheetImages;
    this.spritesheetList   = {};
}

Tileset.prototype.loadTiles =  function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = this.spritesheetImages.length; i < len; i++) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = this.spritesheetImages[i];

        this.spritesheetList[this.spritesheetImages[i]] = [];

        for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                this.spritesheetList[this.spritesheetImages[i]].push(image.getSubimage(x*16, y*16, 32, 32));
            }
        }
    }
};

Tileset.prototype.getTile = function(spritesheetImage, tileIndex) {
    return this.spritesheetList[spritesheetImage][tileIndex];
};

var tileset = new Tileset(["TilesetA.png","TilesetB.png","TilesetC.png"]);

tileset.loadTiles();

tileset.getTile("TilesetA.png", 132);
```

Now you can create a tilemap every time you need to. I used prototype methods, because then the functions aren't copied with every instance. Hope that's what you intended.

**Edit**

To add a new spritesheet image you can use this method

```
Tileset.prototype.addSpritesheetImage = function(spritesheetImage) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = spritesheetImage;

    this.spritesheetList[spritesheetImage] = [];

    for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            this.spritesheetList[spritesheetImage].push(image.getSubimage(x*16, y*16, 32, 32));
        }
    }
};
```

If you want to use the spritesheet index you can change the getTile method to

```
Tileset.prototype.getTile = function(spritesheetIndex, tileIndex) {
    return this.spritesheetList[Object.keys(this.spritesheetList)[spritesheetIndex]][tileIndex];
};
```

Comment: yeah sorry they're all suppose to be 32 my bad. I didn't see that. I don't need it reusable but I am planning on adding more spritesheets as I go. This is sort of what I need, I guess it would be easier to refer to the spritesheets by a number or a string for their src.